# Java Same method signature different implementation

Tags: java

I have a java class ClassA which has fields and methods as

```java
boolean isAvail;
String field1;

public String setField1(String field1) {
    this.field1 = field1;
}

public boolean isAvail() {
    return isAvail;
}
```

However as per business requirements I need to implement the method as

```java
public String setField1(String bCode) {
    if (isAvail) {
        field1 = bcode;
    }
    else {
        field1 = "XYZ";
    }
}
```

I would like to keep the earlier setField1 as this class is used by other classes and may require the earlier method.

I know it is not feasible to have the same method signature but can anyone provide an insight as to how this can be resolved in an effecient way.

Comment: You can't have the same method signature in the same class.

Comment: It seems unlikely to me that 'business requirements' would be as specific as to require a particular method implementation. Perhaps you could clarify exactly what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 4):

You could have a custom subclass extending the current class, and then override the setField1 method:

```java
public class SubClass extends CurrentClass {

    @Override
    public String setField1(String bCode) {
        if (isAvail()) {
            return super.setField1(bCode);
        } else {
            return super.setField1("XYZ");
        }
    }

}
```

Use SubClass for your new requirements, and let the *old classes* use the CurrentClass like before.